Getting the table name with the newest create data from a database in PySpark (Databricks) to pass to other queries
How do I get the newest table name created in a DB (in Databricks), that has tables created once a week (names like output_20240530)  show tables in "output_" does not give me a date when the tables were created  Thanks, Lou
I can use the following and look through the results, but I need to pass the name to other queries and not have the person running the notebook have to do this
show tables in "DB" like "output_"

If you have Unity Catalog in your Databricks workspace this is very easy:
select table_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
order by CREATED desc
limit 1

link to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/information-schema/tables
If you don't have Unity Catalog, you will have to use this (inefficient) script:
#imports
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, TimestampType
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc

#create empty dataframe
schema = StructType([
    StructField("table_name", StringType()), StructField("createdAt", TimestampType())
])
tables_df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)
#run describe for each table in the schema
database = "dwh"
for i in spark.sql(f"show tables in {database} like 'output_'").collect():
    table_name = i["tableName"]
    table_details_df =spark.sql(f"describe detail {database}.{table_name}").select("name","createdAt")
    tables_df = tables_df.unionAll(table_details_df)
#get the table name for the last created table
last_crated_table = tables_df.orderBy(tables_df.createdAt.desc()).head(1)[0][0]


Thanks Chen!  This is getting me very close.  How do I filter for table names that start with output_ like output_20240530?  The DB is used for many different table names, and the query as is gets me other names that are newer, like input_20240531.  THANKS AGAIN

@LouRadwan I edited the answer to add the filter: "show tables in {database} like 'output_'"

Thanks Chen.  I was able to add one line late last week (if "ani_" in table_name:), that did the same:
table_name = i["tableName"]
if "ani_" in table_name:
    table_details_df =spark.sql(f"describe detail {database}.{table_name}").select("name","createdAt")

This was a big help, as I am just starting with Databricks and Python
